subdivision/bevel problem



How to fix this jagged edge that appears after I apply modifiers?

Choose Limit Method > None so that the bevel also happens on this edge, it will prevent your problem, or do a manual bevel:


A subdivision after the bevel still produces weird artifacts for me.

https://imgur.com/a/t4WHemg
Now I have this problem and it still doesn't look ok

Is there a reason why you prefer a Bevel modifier rather than a manual one?

IDK, I guess I'm going to do it manually

Yes, I think it's better, you'll have a full control on the geometry
